# Displaying Saved Images in iOS 5

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

I have an app that I am saving images to the NSDocumentDirectory.  I can see that the path is being set correctly but when I try to retrieve them the NSData is null.

Here are some of my snippets..

```
NSData *imageData  = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp"];

//Create unique filename
CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
CFStringRef newUniqueIdString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:(__bridge_transfer NSString *)newUniqueIdString];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathExtension: @"png"];

[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];         

[self showPhoto:path];
```

Then in my showPhoto method

```
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
```

If I debug pngData it is 0 bytes but my path show what I think is the correct path?

Any way of debugging if the photo is actually on the phone?  Im not sure if it is getting saved or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this and check if the file exists first and use imageWithContentsOfFile: to retrieve it.

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:localFilePath];
bool fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];

if(fileExists == YES)
{
    UIImage *_image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath]
}
```

If the image is still empty then there is something wrong with your image.

Comment: fileExists is coming back false.  false on simulator and phone.

Comment: i removed the unique id and extra path thinking that was messing it up.  not saving the image for some reason.

Comment: I recommend you double check exactly where you are saving files because it looks like you might be saving them to one directory and calling it from another. As you might have guess already if "fileExists" returns false then it means that the file you're trying to get doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 on the iExplorer.  that helped alot.  call me stupid but i thought i was running the latest build on the phone, i was not.  it turned out the files were being saved in the temp directory instead of the documents directory.

my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you running app in simulator you can find application files here: /Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications

If you debugging on iPhone you can use [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to see files on iPhone.

Comment: that makese sense.  the files are not found in the documents directory.